# Importing CSV data to Neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j

I am trying to load csv in neo4j. However, I am getting the following error:-

```
@ position 9738 -  there's a field starting with a quote and whereas it ends that quote there seems to be characters in that field after that ending quote. That isn't supported. This is what I read: '    0   128     "           
201 Filesystem  File                                    "dd'
```

The main reason is that one column in that CSV file contains multiple lines of text (including double quote). I am also attaching one such example -

```
9029    AST AST_METHOD  MODIFIER_PUBLIC,MODIFIER_STATIC 33      0   9025    EMAIL   ""  37  get_email_content   "/**
     * Get the email content from the correct file.
     * @since  1.0.0
     * @static
     * @param  string $template_name Template to load.
     * @param  array  $args          Arguments passed to the template file.
     * @return string                Email contents.
     */"
```

Can you suggest me a way to resolve this issue? I think there can be two ways

1. convert multilines to a single line,
2. Read CSV in a way that consider those multi lines as a single line.

I am not sure how to do it either way. Feel free to jump in with different idea as well.

Comment: Best to preprocess your CSV file in your favorite scripting language or Excel, Google spreadsheet, etc...